# How to disable SSL for asp.net core projects in vs2017？

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1

I want to disable ssl in a asp.net core 2.1 project. I'm using vs2017. After I unchecked SSL in the project's attribute, the code of front area is working well, but the css,js,and images file in another area cannot be found, the chrome show that "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR", so how do I fix it?